# how to get std::list <std::string>::iterator to output error value?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I'm searching through a list of values, and want to have it return some sort of 'default' error value when it cant find the value to search for. I don't mean `std::cerr`. i mean a value that i can use in my program like a bool. However, if it does find the string, I need the pointer value of where it is in the string. How do I do this?

Comment: `std::cerr` isn't anything remotely like an "error value"; it's a **place (stream) where you can output error messages**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef std::list<std::string> MyList;
MyList  mylist;
MyList::iterator iter = mylist.find("somestring");
if (iter != mylist.end() ) {
   // the string was found
} else {
   // the string was not found
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic way is to return an iterator (not a pointer), and return the end iterator when the element was not found.

But you don't need to write this, because `<algorithm>` already contains [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).